# 404 Error when I try to integrate JIRA with GitHub Enterprise

Tags: github, oauth, http-status-code-404, jira, dvcs

I am trying to integrate my GitHub Enterprise account with JIRA via the steps documented here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Linking+a+bitbucket+or+GitHub+repository+with+JIRA+OnDemand

However, after I complete the process and hit "Add" and "Continue," I receive a 404 error from GitHub.

I've looked on JIRA's support site as well as here--can't find a solution. Does anyone know of one or a workaround? I'm thinking this is a bug.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a know issue.
Atlassian is tracking it here: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/DCON-358

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and just got it working. Make sure you set the URLs correctly in GitHub, both the callback URL and the authorization URL should look something like `https://mycompany.atlassian.net` if you are using hosted JIRA.

Answer (score 0):

This issue sounds to me that it more likely has something to do with the GitHub repository access and the repository not being publicly accessible.

Check to see that the links within Jira are referencing an open and publicly accessible GitHub repository OR that your logged into your GitHub account that your trying to integrate with; using the same browser your also accessing Jira from.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was removing my user name from the url:

[image]

Comment: this works for me as far as authorizing in GitHub, but when I'm redirected to Jira, I get a message saying it can't connect to my organization